imoprt glb file in react
Can anyone help me? The file sky.glb is not working in my project. but the another file work corectly
import { useGLTF } from '@react-three/drei'
import React from 'react'
import skyScene from '../assets/3d/sky.glb'

const Sky = () => {
  const sky = useGLTF(skyScene);
  return (
    <mesh>
    <primitive  object={sky.scene}/>
    </mesh>
  )
}

export default Sky


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
